# how do i solve the errors within this code?

Tags: python, tkinter, project

This is my code for the login page i added a registration button so when the user presses it there automatically taken to the registration page but when i do it returns errors

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Label, Entry, Button

class LoginPage:
    def __init__(self):
        self.loginPage = Tk()
        self.loginPage.title('Login')
        self.loginPage.geometry('550x510+400+100')
        self.loginPage.configure(bg='#075897')
        self.loginPage.resizable(False, False)

        self.frame = Frame(self.loginPage, width=350, height=350, bg='#075897')
        self.frame.place(x=115, y=40)
        self.heading = Label(self.frame, text='Unidirect', fg='black', bg='#075897', font=('Roboto', 25, 'bold'))
        self.heading.place(x=80, y=15)

        self.lblEmail = Entry(self.frame, width=25, border=0, fg='black', bg='#075897', font=('Roboto', 9))
        self.lblEmail.place(x=45, y=100)
        self.lblEmail.insert(0, 'Email')
        self.lblEmail.bind('<FocusIn>', self.on_enter)
        self.lblEmail.bind('<FocusOut>', self.on_leave)
        Frame(self.frame, width=230, height=1, bg='Pink').place(x=45, y=120)

        self.lblPassword = Entry(self.frame, width=25, border=0, fg='black', bg='#075897', font=('Times New Roman', 9))
        self.lblPassword.place(x=45, y=150)
        self.lblPassword.insert(0, 'Password')
        self.lblPassword.bind('<FocusIn>', self.on_enter)
        self.lblPassword.bind('<FocusOut>', self.on_leave)
        Frame(self.frame, width=230, height=1, bg='black').place(x=45, y=170)

        self.btnLogin = Button(self.frame, width=24, text='Log In', fg='black', bg='#075897', highlightbackground='blue',
                          activeforeground='black', activebackground='#36bbf1', cursor='hand2', border=1, font=('Roboto', 11, 'bold'))
        self.btnLogin.place(x=25, y=210)

        self.txtRegister = Label(self.frame, text="Don't have an account?", fg='black', bg='#075897', font=('Arial', 9))
        self.txtRegister.place(x=75, y=245)

        self.btnRegisterPage = Button(self.frame, width=6, text='Register', border=0, fg='black', bg='#075897', activeforeground='black',
                                activebackground='#075897', cursor='hand2', font=('Roboto', 9, 'bold underline'), command=self.show_registration_page)
        self.btnRegisterPage.place(x=230, y=245)

        self.forgotPassword = Button(self.frame, text='Forgot Password?', bd=0, fg='black', bg='#075897', activeforeground='black',
                                activebackground='#075897', cursor='hand2', font=('Times New Roman', 9))
        self.forgotPassword.place(x=175, y=180)

    def on_enter(self, e):
        if e.widget == self.lblEmail:
            self.lblEmail.delete(0, 'end')
        elif e.widget == self.lblPassword:
            self.lblPassword.delete(0, 'end')

    def on_leave(self, e):
        if e.widget == self.lblEmail:
            if self.lblEmail.get() == '':
                self.lblEmail.insert(0, 'Email')
        elif e.widget == self.lblPassword:
            if self.lblPassword.get() == '':
                self.lblPassword.insert(0, 'Password')

    def show_registration_page(self):
        self.loginPage.withdraw()
        RegistrationPage()

class RegistrationPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        registration_frame=super().__init__()
        label_firstname = Label(self, text="First Name:")
        label_firstname.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)
        entry_firstname = Entry(registration_frame)
        entry_firstname.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=5)

        label_lastname = Label(self, text="Last Name:")
        label_lastname.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)
        entry_lastname = Entry(registration_frame)
        entry_lastname.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=5)

        label_email = Label(self, text="Email:")
        label_email.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)
        entry_email = Entry(registration_frame)
        entry_email.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=5)

        label_password = Label(self, text="Password:")
        label_password.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)
        entry_password = Entry(registration_frame, show="*")
        entry_password.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=5)
      

        self.btnRegister = Button(self.frame, width=24, text='Register', fg='black', bg='#075897', highlightbackground='blue',
                              activeforeground='black', activebackground='#36bbf1', cursor='hand2', border=1, font=('Roboto', 11, 'bold'))
        self.btnRegister.place(x=25, y=210)
        self.pack()
        self.registrationPage.mainloop()


LoginPage()
```

i tried to create a frame but it keeps returning errors

Comment: _i tried to create a frame but it keeps returning errors_ Are we supposed to guess what the errors are?  Update the question and add the full error messages please.

Comment: It's helpful to always provide the full error message (stacktrace) for errors you are encountering. People may be able to run your code, but that's no guarantee they encounter the same errors, which may be due to code you didn't share, or something in your environment. Note that the code you shared runs without error (but doesn't do anything either, since the application is never really shown)

Answer (score 1):

Your code has several errors:

1. In class `LoginPage` constructor (`__init__()` function) you didn't call

```py
self.loginPage.mainloop()
```

so window wasn't be displayed.

2. `RegistrationPage` inherits `tk.Frame`, so you can't display its content in another window. The right way is to inherit `RegistrationPage` from `tk.Tk`.
3. When you call

```
super().__init__()
```

created object is assigned to `self`, so you don't need to assign `registration_frame` variable. And onwards you can use `self` instead of `registration_frame`.

4. Call `Button(self.frame, ...)` always fails because there isn't `frame` property in `RegistrationPage` class or its parent class. Instead of `self.frame` you can just write `self`.
5. You can't `pack()` a `tk.Tk` object. Just remove this call.
6. Replace

```
self.registrationPage.mainloop()
```

by

```
self.mainloop()
```

(See point 3).

The full code will be

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Label, Entry, Button


class LoginPage:
    def __init__(self):
        self.loginPage = Tk()
        self.loginPage.title('Login')
        self.loginPage.geometry('550x510+400+100')
        self.loginPage.configure(bg='#075897')
        self.loginPage.resizable(False, False)

        self.frame = Frame(self.loginPage, width=350, height=350, bg='#075897')
        self.frame.place(x=115, y=40)
        self.heading = Label(self.frame, text='Unidirect', fg='black', bg='#075897', font=('Roboto', 25, 'bold'))
        self.heading.place(x=80, y=15)

        self.lblEmail = Entry(self.frame, width=25, border=0, fg='black', bg='#075897', font=('Roboto', 9))
        self.lblEmail.place(x=45, y=100)
        self.lblEmail.insert(0, 'Email')
        self.lblEmail.bind('<FocusIn>', self.on_enter)
        self.lblEmail.bind('<FocusOut>', self.on_leave)
        Frame(self.frame, width=230, height=1, bg='Pink').place(x=45, y=120)

        self.lblPassword = Entry(self.frame, width=25, border=0, fg='black', bg='#075897', font=('Times New Roman', 9))
        self.lblPassword.place(x=45, y=150)
        self.lblPassword.insert(0, 'Password')
        self.lblPassword.bind('<FocusIn>', self.on_enter)
        self.lblPassword.bind('<FocusOut>', self.on_leave)
        Frame(self.frame, width=230, height=1, bg='black').place(x=45, y=170)

        self.btnLogin = Button(self.frame, width=24, text='Log In', fg='black', bg='#075897', highlightbackground='blue',
                          activeforeground='black', activebackground='#36bbf1', cursor='hand2', border=1, font=('Roboto', 11, 'bold'))
        self.btnLogin.place(x=25, y=210)

        self.txtRegister = Label(self.frame, text="Don't have an account?", fg='black', bg='#075897', font=('Arial', 9))
        self.txtRegister.place(x=75, y=245)

        self.btnRegisterPage = Button(self.frame, width=6, text='Register', border=0, fg='black', bg='#075897', activeforeground='black',
                                activebackground='#075897', cursor='hand2', font=('Roboto', 9, 'bold underline'), command=self.show_registration_page)
        self.btnRegisterPage.place(x=230, y=245)

        self.forgotPassword = Button(self.frame, text='Forgot Password?', bd=0, fg='black', bg='#075897', activeforeground='black',
                                activebackground='#075897', cursor='hand2', font=('Times New Roman', 9))
        self.forgotPassword.place(x=175, y=180)

        self.loginPage.mainloop()

    def on_enter(self, e):
        if e.widget == self.lblEmail:
            self.lblEmail.delete(0, 'end')
        elif e.widget == self.lblPassword:
            self.lblPassword.delete(0, 'end')

    def on_leave(self, e):
        if e.widget == self.lblEmail:
            if self.lblEmail.get() == '':
                self.lblEmail.insert(0, 'Email')
        elif e.widget == self.lblPassword:
            if self.lblPassword.get() == '':
                self.lblPassword.insert(0, 'Password')

    def show_registration_page(self):
        # self.loginPage.withdraw()
        RegistrationPage()


class RegistrationPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        label_firstname = Label(self, text="First Name:")
        label_firstname.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)
        entry_firstname = Entry(self)
        entry_firstname.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=5)

        label_lastname = Label(self, text="Last Name:")
        label_lastname.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)
        entry_lastname = Entry(self)
        entry_lastname.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=5)

        label_email = Label(self, text="Email:")
        label_email.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)
        entry_email = Entry(self)
        entry_email.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=5)

        label_password = Label(self, text="Password:")
        label_password.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)
        entry_password = Entry(self, show="*")
        entry_password.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=5)

        self.btnRegister = Button(self, width=24, text='Register', fg='black', bg='#075897', highlightbackground='blue',
                              activeforeground='black', activebackground='#36bbf1', cursor='hand2', border=1, font=('Roboto', 11, 'bold'))
        self.btnRegister.place(x=25, y=210)
        self.pack()
        # self.mainloop()


LoginPage()
```

If I misunderstand you and actually you want to use `RegistrationPage` as a `tk.Frame`, not another window, skip point 4. Also, remove the `self.registrationPage.mainloop()` call.